# GRUB command line problem

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

After installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my new computer (alongside Windows on a separate hard drive) (I got an error before rebooting that said I might have to reinstall some packages manually (or something like that)), The only thing I get after turning the computer on is GRUB in command-line mode

I would like to avoid reformatting the drives as I have installed Microsoft Flight Simulator on the Windows partition and I would like to avoid going through the 12-hour installation again...

Edit: I found out that there is a boot menu option for Windows Boot Manager which lets me boot into windows...

Edit: I somehow managed to boot in both operating systems but there is no GRUB bootloader and the computer starts in Windows (The only way to boot in Ubuntu is to enter the BIOS boot menu, select the GRUB partition (now loads correctly)and select Ubuntu (there is no Windows option)

```
GNU GRUB version 2.04

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.

grub> _
```

Comment: Are you sure you have installed both systems in UEFI boot mode? If so, is Windows fast start up off as that sets hibernation flag and prevents grub from booting Windows. Post link from Boot-Repair before running any autofix. Normally autofix works, but very occasionally it makes things worse. Best to review configuration first. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**commands to type to boot into linux:**

`ls`

(then choose number for your drive)

`set root="(partition you chosen)"`

`linux /boot/vmli (and press tab to autocomplete) set root=/dev/sda`

`initrd /boot/init (and press tab to autocomplete)`

`boot`

after booting into OS - download boot repair via command :

`sudo apt install boot-repair` or if it doesn't work : `sudo apt install boot-repair-gui`

click on "quick fix" or any similar button (if your system requires - you can modify that via advanced settings but i don't recommend that for you cause as i see your not best in linux)

wait a while and your boot should be fixed :)

Comment: Thank you, it did not work but now, I somehow managed to boot in both operating systems but there is no GRUB bootloader and the computer starts in Windows (The only way to boot in Ubuntu is to enter the BIOS boot menu, select the GRUB partition (now loads correctly)and select Ubuntu (there is no Windows option)

Comment: as it didn't worked - it means that just partition is broken and you'll need to reinstall. TAKE BACKUP!!!
PS: mostly windows is creating bugs like this after OS update (and because of that i wasn't touching windows for a long time - i wasn't updating)

Comment: Are you sure that I cannot fix the bootloaders? both OS work fine..

Comment: a! bootloaders - just boot into ubuntu for one time install boot-repair and run `quick fix`

Comment: Please provide that as an answer. Also mention sudo os-prober / sudo update-grub

Comment: okey, gonnna do it ;)

Comment: and about os-prober, boot repair have it built-in, so i don't need to say about it ;)